# Keep parent process in foreground after fork

Tags: c, fork, tty

I have a C program that forks a child process, which I'm running from a linux shell.

My problem is that, after forking, the parent process moves to the shell background.  I would like the parent process to stay in the foreground.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("Before Fork\n");
        sleep(1);
    }

    printf("forking...\n");
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid) {
        // child
        printf("Child started and now exiting\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    // parent
    wait(NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("After Fork\n");
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (with comment added later)

```
Before Fork
Before Fork
Before Fork
forking...
Child started and now exiting
After Fork
gregp@gregp-ubuntu:~/fork_example$ After Fork       # <--- User returned to shell
After Fork
```

Notice that shortly after the fork, the user is returned to the shell prompt, and the program continues running in the background.  I do not want this to happen.  I want the program to continue running in the foreground.

**Desired Output** (with comment added later)

```
Before Fork
Before Fork
Before Fork
forking...
Child started and now exiting
After Fork
After Fork
After Fork
                 # Program now exits and user returns to shell
gregp@gregp-ubuntu:~/fork_example$
```

Comment: `if (pid) {
        // child` wrong. The parent gets a nonzero pid returned, the child a zero one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

th pid is returned in the parent, so your condition should be

```
if (!pid)
```

because the child in your code will not go to the if. that's because

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent,
>   and 0 is returned in the child. On failure, -1 is returned in the
>   parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

Comment: Good call, that was the problem.

Comment: Will when it lets me.  It says "You can accept an answer in 5 minutes".

Answer (score 2):

fork() return 0 to child process, on success.

If loop will not execute when condition is zero.

so if child want to execute you have to change if condition into

```
if(!pid)
```

further details [man fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)

Answer (score 1):

#### Incipient problem

You need a loop around the [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html).  As written, it waits for one child to finish (ignoring the PID returned and not setting the status).  The shell's `wait` command is different from the system call — but the code looks as though it was written by analogy with the shell's command.

#### Immediate problem

*Identified by others first — they get the credit, please.*

The `wait()` loop problem is only relevant after you've fixed the `if (pid)` test ... I wonder if you'd have made the mistake if you wrote `if (pid == 0) { // Child`?  Probably not; you know the `fork()` returns the PID of the child to the parent and zero to the child.  Explicitness helps.

Comment: I don't think adding a loop around the wait() will fix my problem.  First of all, there is only one child process, so a single wait should suffice.  Secondly, even if I move the wait to the bottom of my program (and lets assume the child runs for a long time), I'd like the parent to remain in the fg.

Comment: The loop becomes relevant once you fix the child/parent identification process.  Assuming you want the parent process to wait for all its (direct) children to exit.  Since the children exit quickly, it won't matter whether you wait in the `sleep()` or with a loop around `wait()`.  If you changed the children so that they lasted some time (say more than 3 seconds) before exiting, then the loop would matter.